# How to set object (rectangle, circle, freehand draw, etc) type at runtime using fabric.js

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, geometry, fabricjs

I'm a beginner to [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/). I have a canvas and I'm giving background to canvas. I want to draw following types of objects on image as given below.

1. Text
2. Circle
3. Rectangle
4. FreeHand Drawing

I'm selecting these type of object through dropdown. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skhurams/cbosagm9/).

Here is my code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="ddlSelectionType" onchange="">
        <option value="1">Rectangle</option>
        <option value="0">Text</option>
        <option value="2">Circle</option>
        <option value="3">Free Hand Mode</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trComments">
    <td>
      select comments
      <select id="ddlCommnets">
        <option value="0">No Commnets</option>
        <option value="1">Abc </option>
        <option value="2">XYZ </option>
        <option value="3">Lmnop</option>
        <option value="4">WFSSS</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="btnApplyComments" type="button" value="Apply Comments" onclick="createText()" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    select font color  <input id="btnColor" type="color" name="favcolor" value="#0C32FF">
    </td>
    <td>
     select font size  <input id="bntfontsize" type="number" name="favcolor" value="20" min="10" max="30">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="divJsonText">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="setJson" onclick="setfabricTextToJson()" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="getJson" onclick="getfabricJsonToText()" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value=" Delete selected object(s) " id="delete" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset()" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<canvas id="wmcCanvas" width="600" height="800">
  Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
```

When there is text selected from select draw type dropdown then I have to select text as comments from second dropdown.

If I select rectangle from the dropdown then everything works fine, but if I select text first and try to apply text from dropdown comments then there are exceptions, and after that if I want to draw rectangle then it's not drawn.

Answer (score 0):

1. Draw div with set image background in css and make !important to background
2. now overlap to  in it
3. write code to make rectangle

**Code**:

```
<div class="backgroumdImageCss">
   <canvas></canvas>
</div>
<script>
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', { selection: false });
canvas.setHeight(250);
canvas.setWidth(1068.5);          
        rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left:25,
        top: 35,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        width:150,
        height:520,
        angle: 0,
        fill:red,
        transparentCorners: false
        });
        canvas.add(rect);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', { selection: false });
var rect, isDown, origX, origY, obj=new Array(),wdt,hgt,col='red',per=0;
canvas.setHeight(250);
canvas.setWidth(1068.5);
canvas.selection = false;
canvas1.on('mouse:down', function(o){
    isDown1 = true;
    var pointer1 = canvas1.getPointer(o.e);
    origX1 = pointer1.x;
    origY1 = pointer1.y;
    var pointer1 = canvas1.getPointer(o.e);
    rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
        left: origX1,
        top: origY1,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        width: pointer1.x-origX1,
        height: pointer1.y-origY1,
        angle: 0,
        fill:col1,
        transparentCorners: false,
        opacity:.8
    });
    canvas1.add(rect1);

});
canvas1.on('mouse:move', function(o){
    if (!isDown1) return;
    var pointer1 = canvas1.getPointer(o.e);

    if(origX1>pointer1.x){
        rect1.set({ left: Math.abs(pointer1.x) });
    }
    if(origY1>pointer1.y){
        rect1.set({ top: Math.abs(pointer1.y) });
    }

    wdt1=Math.abs(origX1 - pointer1.x);
    hgt1=Math.abs(origY1 - pointer1.y);

    rect1.set({ width: Math.abs(origX1 - pointer1.x) });
    rect1.set({ height: Math.abs(origY1 - pointer1.y) });


    canvas1.renderAll();
});

    canvas1.on('mouse:up', function(o){
      isDown1 = false;
        newobj1=new Array(origX1,origY1,wdt1,hgt1,col1);
        //alert(newobj1);
        obj1.push(newobj1);
        json_obj1 = JSON.stringify(obj1);

    });
</script>
```